# How to store tickboxes/dropdown in the database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

See the UI design below:

[image]

An Item can have more than 1 group of tickboxes and/or dropdowns, how do I store these data in the database?

I have come up with this database design:

`items` table:

```
+----+--------------+
| id | name         |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | Plain Burger |
+----+--------------+
```

`extra_group` table:

```
+----+---------+--------+--------------------+--------------+
| id | item_id | name   | description        | control_type |
+----+---------+--------+--------------------+--------------+
|  1 |       1 | Sauces |                    | checkboxes   |
|  2 |       1 | extras | Choose your extras | dropdown     |
+----+---------+--------+--------------------+--------------+
```

and finally `extras` table:

```
+----+----------------+------------------+------+
| id | extra_group_id | value            | cost |
+----+----------------+------------------+------+
|  1 |              1 | with Kitchup     | 0.00 |
|  2 |              1 | with Mayo        | 0.00 |
|  3 |              2 | with Boiled Rice | 0.00 |
|  4 |              2 | with Chips       | 0.00 |
+----+----------------+------------------+------+
```

Is this the correct way of database design or what can be improved?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good,
I would be inclined to add a table between item and extra_group (and remove the item_id from extra_group)

item_extra_group table:

```
+---------+----------------+
| item_id | extra_group_id | 
+---------+----------------+
|  1      | 1              | 
|  1      | 2              | 
+---------+----------------+
```

This will enable you to model a many-to many relationship,
as I would guess that you will have lots of repeating extra_groups e.g (cheese burger, bacon burger) would probably all have the same extras?

Comment: That is very good idea! Yep I will have a lot of repeating group (extras) for cheese burger, chicken burger, etc. Thanks.

Comment: This is a good catch (+1) regarding saving some maintenance of repeating groups on the definition of extra_groups, but it doesn't address the fact that the `extras` table is still only 2NF.

Answer (score 1):

That design is just fine. You used the [third normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form), which is the accepted way of doing this sort of things.

Comment: How do you feel about spitting extras value into separate table? There will be a lot duplicate values of extras.

Comment: What values are you talking about? Whether or not a checkbox was checked?

Comment: To be proper 3NF, it is likely that you want another table like "extras_menu" that has the `value` and `cost` fields from `extras`.  Then the `extras` table would instead have an FK to `extras_menu`.  This assumes that extras always have the same cost, regardless of the item that they are served with.

Comment: @Joel: I don't agree. Putting both `value` and `cost` into a new table just adds an additional redirection without any benefit.

Comment: The additional benefit is normalization of the description and cost of extras.  If the business rule is that extras cost the same regardless of what you add them to, then the cost (as well as the name of the extra) is not dependent on the PK of `extras` and OP's `extras` table is 2NF not 3NF.  If, on the other hand, the cost of each extra can vary by the item it is added to and if you can spell the name of the extra differently on each item then OP's extras table _is_ 3NF after all, but I suspect it would be better to normalize these attributes out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you should do to tweak your design, which is pretty good now, but could be improved slightly:

`items` table:

```
+----+--------------+ 
| id | name         | 
+----+--------------+ 
|  1 | Plain Burger | 
+----+--------------+
```

`extra_group` table:

```
+----+---------+--------+--------------------+--------------+ 
| id | item_id | name   | description        | control_type | 
+----+---------+--------+--------------------+--------------+ 
|  1 |       1 | Sauces |                    | checkboxes   | 
|  2 |       1 | extras | Choose your extras | dropdown     | 
+----+---------+--------+--------------------+--------------+
```

A **new** table `options` like so:

```
+-----------+------------------+------+ 
| option_id | description      | cost | 
+-----------+------------------+------+ 
|  10       | with Kitchup     | 0.00 | 
|  11       | with Mayo        | 0.00 | 
|  12       | with Boiled Rice | 0.00 | 
|  13       | with Chips       | 0.00 | 
+----+------+------------------+------+
```

A **modified** `extras` table:

```
+----+----------------+-----------+
| id | extra_group_id | option_id |
+----+----------------+-----------+ 
|  1 |              1 |        10 |
|  2 |              1 |        11 |
|  3 |              2 |        12 | 
|  4 |              2 |        13 | 
+----+----------------+-----------+
```

This design is in 3NF and will make your data maintenance much simpler and will avoid problems of inconsistent pricing of extra items.